# vsftpd seems to require 777 on web root

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, vsftpd

Am currently setting up vsftpd on a server and am struggling with the permissions.

I created an ftpuser and set its home directory to /web (/web is a symlink to /usr/share/nginx/ - contains the www folder etc). Playing with permissions it seems like the only chmod that will let me write is 777 - even though ftpuser is a member of the www-data group which is the owner/group of the folders & files?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

### [Please read this Wikipedia article on Unix file permissions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions)

Do nothing further until you have read and understood the contents of that page.  Unix permissions are not some mysterious voodoo magic - they are incredibly logical and simple once you understand them.
Take the time required to understand what those "magic" numbers mean, and what they do.

---

With your newfound clarity and understanding of Unix file/directory permissions and ownership you should now know that `vsftpd` does not *require* any particular permissions, the operating system is just enforcing the restrictions you've given it.

The permissions on a file or directory *determine who may perform what actions*.  You as the system administrator are responsible for setting *appropriate* permissions on files and directories (which users/groups will need to perform what actions, and what actions "other" users should be permitted to perform).

You determine what permissions are *appropriate* by the configuration of your server, and which users need to perform which actions in your particular environment.